# Supremum of a probabilistic function with ambiguity distribution set using Wasserstein metric

Tags: stochastic-programming, robust-optimization, polyhedra, probability-theory

There is a proof of how to derive distributionally robust chance constraints with ellipsoid bound.

$$\inf_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{D}^{WD}} \mathbb{P}\{\|\mathbf{A\zeta-b}\|_2 \leq 1\} \geq 1-\epsilon$$

leads to

$$\sup_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{D}^{WD}}\mathrm{CVaR}_\epsilon (\|\mathbf{A\zeta-b}\|_2-1) \leq 0$$

Here, the Wasserstein ambituity set ${\mathcal{D}_{\rho}^{DW}}$

is centered around
${\mathbb{\hat{P}}^M=\frac{1}{M}\sum\delta_{\zeta_i}}$ with radius ${\rho}$

$$ \mathbb{P}:\{ d_{WD} (\mathbb{P},\mathbb{\hat{P}}^M) \leq\rho\}$$

Based on the definition of CVaR and min-max theorem in [Ref](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8814677/), the right-hand side of CVaR can be written as

$$
\sup_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{D}^{DW}} \inf_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}} [\max(\|\mathbf{A\zeta-b}\|_2-1+t,0) -t\epsilon] \leq 0
$$

Which is furthur derived as

$$
\inf_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \sup_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{D}^{DW}} \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}} [\max(\|\mathbf{A\zeta-b}\|_2-1+t,0) -t\epsilon] \leq 0
$$

And

$$\inf_{t \in \mathbb{R}} \sup_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{D}^{DW}} \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}} [\max(\|\mathbf{A\zeta-b}\|_2-1+t,0) -t\epsilon]$$

$$ \leq \sup_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{D}^{DW}} \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}} [\max(\|\mathbf{A\zeta-b}\|_2-1+t,0) -t\epsilon]$$

$$\leq \rho \|\mathbf{A}\|_{2} + \frac{1}{M} \sum[\max(\|\mathbf{A\zeta-b}\|_2-1+t,0) - t\epsilon]$$

I would like to learn how to perform the transformation using the polyhedra function, not the ellipsoid one.
That is

$$\sup_{\mathbb{P}\in\mathcal{D}^{DW}} \mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{P}} [\max(\mathbf{D\zeta-q}+t,0) -t\epsilon]$$